# How I get only few specified columns from a text file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, text-files

I have a text file with 20 columns(columns are seperated by |) and many rows. How can I read only the columns 5,9,17 ?

Comment: Please don't ask 2 very similar questions within 1 hours. You can always edit the original question instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read a file like this (called text.txt in my example)

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4
2 | 3 | 4 | 5
3 | 4 | 5 | 6
```

just do

```
matrix = dlmread('text.txt');
```

which gives you

```
1     2     3     4
2     3     4     5
3     4     5     6
```

You can then use standard matlab matrix notation to extract for example columns 1 and 4

```
col1 = matrix(:, 1) % the colon is used to tell matlab to take all rows
col4 = matrix(:, 4)
```

Comment: Thank you [tag:lhcgeneva]. But the problem in my text file is there are about 500,000 rows for each column. So if I use dlmread, then I have to read all the columns into matlab and then only I can get the preferred columns. This will take some time and it's a waste of memory. What I want to do is to get only the preferred columns directly from the text file without reading the whole text file.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to form another variable choosing specific columns from the variable array formed by the import of the text file

Answer (score 1):

With the right input parameters, [textscan](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) can pull this off:

```
Ncols = 20;
colExtract = [5 9 17];

fspec = cell(1,Ncols);
fspec(:)={'%*f '}; % the asterisk tells textscan to ignore the column
fspec(colExtract)={'%f '};
fspec{end}=fspec{end}(1:end-1); % removes the space from the last parameter
fspecstr = horzcat(fspec{:});

fid = fopen(filename);
    indata = textscan(fid,fspecstr,'HeaderLines',1,'delimiter','\t');
fclose(fid);

col5 = indata{1};
col9 = indata{2};
col17= indata{3};
```

As you can see, I assumed there was a single headerline and the data is tab delimited. If your application does not have this, change it of course.

I guess it pays of if you're working with huge files from which you only want a small portion or can't have all the content in memory.

Comment: @Magla that's just the same as without the braces. What do you mean with 'work better', that part is not the core of the anwser

Comment: @Magla ah ok, I was testing in octave, where you don't need the braces. Thx!